# Number of natural numbers smaller than a given natural number!

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $m,n$ be natural numbers. Is there a formula or a (non trivial) bound for the number of natural numbers smaller than $n$ and coprime with $m$?

Thanks in advance!